# Avro Scheme Write Union of Null and Double Integer Boolean

Tags: java, hadoop2, avro, cascading

I am trying to convert text files to avro files using Cascading 3.0.2 and avro-scheme 2.5. Below are few fields from the avro schema:

```
{ "type":"record", "name":"root", "namespace":"", "fields":[
{"name":"Key","type":"int","doc":"10,NOT NULL, Max Profiled Length=7, Max Profiled Value=1100367"},
{"name":"SampleCount","type":["int","null"],"doc":"10,NULL"},
{"name":"TestAmount","type":["double","null"] ,"doc":"20,NULL"},
{"name":"SampleAmount","type":["double","null"],"doc":"20,NULL"},
{"name":"Comments","type":["null","string"],"doc":"100,NULL"},
{"name":"ActiveFg","type":"boolean","doc":"5,NOT NULL"},
{"name":"MaxChangedDt","type":"string","doc":"20,NOT NULL,YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS,Last Record Changed Date."}
]
}
```

When i try to run the conversion program with the above schema i get the following error:

```
Error for Sample 1:
Caused by: org.apache.avro.UnresolvedUnionException: Not in union ["int","null"]: 1
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData.resolveUnion(GenericData.java:600)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.resolveUnion(GenericDatumWriter.java:151)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.write(GenericDatumWriter.java:71)
    at org.apache.avro.reflect.ReflectDatumWriter.write(ReflectDatumWriter.java:143)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeField(GenericDatumWriter.java:114)
    at org.apache.avro.reflect.ReflectDatumWriter.writeField(ReflectDatumWriter.java:175)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeRecord(GenericDatumWriter.java:104)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.write(GenericDatumWriter.java:66)
    at org.apache.avro.reflect.ReflectDatumWriter.write(ReflectDatumWriter.java:143)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.write(GenericDatumWriter.java:58)
    at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileWriter.append(DataFileWriter.java:290)
    ... 29 more
Error for Sample 2:
Caused by: org.apache.avro.UnresolvedUnionException: Not in union ["double","null"]: 46.9158
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData.resolveUnion(GenericData.java:600)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.resolveUnion(GenericDatumWriter.java:151)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.write(GenericDatumWriter.java:71)
    at org.apache.avro.reflect.ReflectDatumWriter.write(ReflectDatumWriter.java:143)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeField(GenericDatumWriter.java:114)
    at org.apache.avro.reflect.ReflectDatumWriter.writeField(ReflectDatumWriter.java:175)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeRecord(GenericDatumWriter.java:104)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.write(GenericDatumWriter.java:66)
    at org.apache.avro.reflect.ReflectDatumWriter.write(ReflectDatumWriter.java:143)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.write(GenericDatumWriter.java:58)
    at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileWriter.append(DataFileWriter.java:290)
    ... 29 more
```

Getting similar error for all the double and int union type fields in the file. If i remove the union types for Int and Double and assign not null defaults in the custom Each function it works fine. Can some one help me on a solution to handle nulls in double and integer while writing to avro files without having to assign defaults. The users of the data don't want the actual data values modified from what is coming in source. I don't want to write the data as String either. Union of null, string works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Avro 1.8.0 introduces the concept of Logical Types. The logical types help you specify the scale and precision for your input. In your case, you can try giving the following as schema

```
{
    "name":"SampleCount",
    "type":[
        "null",
        "int"
    ],
    "logicalType":"decimal",
    "precision":4
}
```

Do try this. The link for the documentation is [here](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.0/spec.html#Decimal)

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try with swapping "null" as first type and setting default to null

```
"type":["null","int"], "default": null
```

Comment: Tried that. Gives same error. I tried running with debug and the problem the record conversion from Cascading object[] to datum using Avro Wrapper is not carry forwarding the data type and trying to write integer, double and booleans as string.  Null values work fine. Am working on a fix on Cascading side in avro-scheme.